# How do I implement popup dialog for login in Android that never pops up until logout?

Tags: java, android, authentication, popup, sharedpreferences

I am trying to do the code in android for first time showing the dialog **popup** for login screen and after login the **popup** will be removed and after that it will not open until you do not logout from the screen.

Comment: Keep a flag in shared preference based on that show/hide popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a boolean variable i.e. True or False value in **SQLite database** or **Shared Preference**... Check its value whenever someone is opening your app If true than dont show Login screen otherwise Show login Screen :)

You can check boolean variable when your app is showing Splash Screen ...

Answer (score 0):

For this, first set value in `SharedPreference` as `false`. Every time when you open the app, check value from `SharedPreference`. If it is false, then show the login popup.

Once login is successfully performed, set value as `true` in shared preference and again set it to  `false` on logout.

Answer (score 0):

use `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences preferences =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
//login success
preferences.edit().putBoolean("login",true).commit();
//logout success
preferences.edit().putBoolean("login",false).commit();
//Whether the display dialog
boolean isLogin = preferences.getBoolean("login",false);
if(!isLogin){
 showLoginDialog();
}else{
enterHome();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing shared preferences is probably not the best idea since after login you probably have some type of access token or something to use for request authorisation. By saving a boolean, you will have two variables stored that can be used to deduce the same thing. So you can just write a function that checks whether you have a valid token stored or what every it is you use to authorise requests after login.  If you are using the accountmanager or something then you should use that to verify the user is still logged in.